# laravel file paths multiple environments

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have Laravel up and running with my app just fine, but I have a problem with filepaths.

I have a table that shows a list of files that have been uploaded, but before showing the file in the list, I check that the file exists with this:

```
@if(File::exists('/vagrant/my_app/public/uploads/'.$md['file']))
```

my problem is that the file path is different on my local vagrant machine vs my production server. I've got my environments setup for `local` and `production`, but is there a way to check this within the view where I'm using the `if` statement to pull the right path?

EDIT: I've just realised I have the same issue in my `filters.php` file as I use the following to force SSL on production, but don't want to force the SSL on local:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Force SSL
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
});
```

Comment: Prefix with `app()` to get the full path to your install, as in `app() . '/public/whatever'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new config option with the correct path for each environment (much like what happens with database connections).

So, use `app.php` or create a new file within `config` folder and then add the filepath:

```
'myFilePath' => '/vagrant/my_app/public/uploads/'
```

After that, use the config in your if statment

```
@if(File::exists(Config::get('app.myFilePath') . $md['file']))
```